# Find one - many matches between columns in a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ObrH.png)

It has 189437 rows and 2 columns.What I need to do is find out how many Num has more than one ID linked to it (i.e same Num but different ID) and also The visa-versa (same ID but different Num). I need to get how many rows out of the whole has this kind of data . How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby for this purpose.
To find how many Num with different ID :

```py
groups = df.groupby("Num").apply(lambda x: len(set(x["ID"])))
result = sum(groups > 1)
```

And for the other way around :

```py
groups = df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: len(set(x["Num"])))
result = sum(groups > 1)
```

*Edit 1*: As proposed by @Grzegorz Skibinski in comment, nunique() may be more concise, so :

```py
result = sum(df.groupby("Num")["ID"].nunique() > 1)
```

*Edit 2*: Benchmark

I created dataframe with 2 columns (integer and str)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000_000),
    "col2": ["".join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase[:5], 3)) for _ in range(1000_000)]
})
```

Counting on the str column: `nunique()` wins over `len(set())`.
However Counting on the int column: `len(set())` wins over `nunique()`

```py
%%timeit -n 10
df.groupby("col1").apply(lambda x: len(set(x["col2"])))
# output: 10 loops, best of 5: 467 ms per loop

%%timeit -n 10
df.groupby("col1")["col2"].nunique()
# output: 10 loops, best of 5: 296 ms per loop

%%timeit -n 10
df.groupby("col2").apply(lambda x: len(set(x["col1"])))
# output: 10 loops, best of 5: 286 ms per loop

%%timeit -n 10
df.groupby("col2")["col1"].nunique()
# output: 10 loops, best of 5: 306 ms per loop
```

Comment: Consider `groups = df.groupby("Num")["ID"].nunique()` instead

Comment: Also works @Grzegorz. However I experienced that when working with large data, `set` is faster than `nunique()`. But it might not hold true in all cases of course

Comment: @Alka - can you share any example, where `.apply(lambda x: len(set(x["col"])))` is faster than `.nunique()`?

Comment: I don't have the example at hand as it is something I did at work (even though, if I remember well, it was about taking unique values instead of nunique). Nevertheless I agree in fact that your formulation is more concise, so I'll edit the answer to include it

Comment: Ok - `.unique()` Vs `set()` is different question, which I would agree might come out for `set()`. `nunique()` doesn't seem to be a question though (I did benchmarking - it comes 3-4x faster on various sizes of data samples, containing integers - I can't possibly think about example, which would have opposite results) - firstly you should avoid `.apply(...)` and use vectorized computation as much as you can - secondly most technologies implement some sort of count distinct function, which is always better than select distinct + count (i.e. don't reinvent the wheel- just go with what you have).

Comment: Well, a downside of such benchmarks is that they are bound to the specificities of the data you use.  I agree most use cases you should just go with the predefined functions such as `nunique()` in our case (more robust and less prone to developer introduced errors, and in most case most performant). However in my experience I learned that when perfs matters a lot, the predefined functions are not always the best choices and user-defined functions/tricks can yield better perfs. I don't know exactly in which conditions you did your benchmrks but check my answer: `nunique` don't always win